# How to style an ionic-segment-button on mobile to look like it's render in the Chrome browser?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic4

When the ion-segment-button is initially rendered in the Chrome browser, it looks like this:

[image: chrome-render-image]

**The above is what I want it to look like on an iOS mobile device.**

When I do render it on an iOS device, it ends up looking like this:

[image: ios-render-image]

I have tried changing the ion-segment mode to Android but it still looks nothing like how it does in the Chrome browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since one of the Ionic 4 beta's you also have to set `mode` on every component.

This means the `ion-segment-button` components as well.

Funny coincidence, as the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335004/is-there-a-way-to-make-ion-segment-look-the-same-on-both-ios-and-android) is right above this in the list :)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [documentation for ion-segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment).

You'll see there is a `mode` property:

> Description: The mode determines which platform styles to use.
>
> Attribute: mode
>
> Type: "ios" | "md"

So you should set the `mode` property to **md** if you want it to always use material design, even on iOS.

```
<ion-segment mode="md">
...
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried that and the ion-segment now looks like [this](https://imgur.com/I5yOCiG). Although this is closer to what I want, it's not the same as how chrome renders it. Thank you though

Comment: Well you’re probably gonna have to set the mode to md for your icons, and other elements as well. Good luck.