# Is there a way to make ion-segment look the same on both iOS and Android?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

After setting the mode of ion-segment, they still look different after rendering them in ionic lab.

I have tried setting the mode of ion-segment and ion-toolbar to "md" but they still look different.

https://ibb.co/HV75Ly2 Here is an image of what they look like after setting the mode.

```
<ion-toolbar mode="md">
    <ion-segment scrollable mode="md">
      <ion-segment-button value="top" checked>
        TOP
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="nfl">
        NFL
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="nba">
        NBA
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="mlb">
        MLB
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="nhl">
        NHL
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="ncaaf">
        NCAAF
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="ncaab">
        NCAAB
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

I would like the ion-segment to look like the android version on both platforms but currently, they still look different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one of the Ionic 4 beta's you also have to set `mode` on every component.

This means the `ion-segment-button` components as well, like:

```
<ion-toolbar mode="md">
    <ion-segment scrollable mode="md">
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="top" checked>
        TOP
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="nfl">
        NFL
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="nba">
        NBA
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="mlb">
        MLB
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="nhl">
        NHL
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="ncaaf">
        NCAAF
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="ncaab">
        NCAAB
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: whoever came along two months later and downvoted this without comment: I got this info direct from the Ionic Team when I reported a bug in my own app during the Ionic 4 beta's, so... ya done me wrong yo!